# How to nest multiple documentclass

Tags: document-classes, nesting, subfiles, document-configuration, documentclass

I would like to create a running diary of documentclass 1 that constitutes multiple instances of documentclass 2, where preferred documentclass 2 is 'minutes'. I am aware of subfiles, but don't know how to use the minutes class with this structure.

MWE:
main.tex

```
\title{Diary}
\documentclass{labbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section*{Meetings}

\subfile{Meetings/20Aug}
%\subfile{Meetings/21Aug} %This will be similar to the one above
%etc...
\end{document}
```

These are the meeting minutes subfile:
20Aug.tex:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles} %This is the normal structure for subfiles
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{mins} % This is the document class I would like and below are its attributes

% \setcommittee{Some Committee Title}
%\setshortcommittee{Committee Short}
%\setmembers{
%   \role{Person}{Job},
%    \role{Another Person}{Another Job},
%    Someone NoJob
%}

%\setdate{[Date], [Scheduled Time]}

%\apologies{Someone Good} %If no-one gives apologies, leave blank and will be dropped
%\absent{Someone Bad} %If no-one is absent, leave blank, and it will be dropped
%\alsopresent{Someone Visitor} %If no-one is a visitor, leave blank and it will be dropped

%\setisAgenda{}%leave as blank for regular minutes. Set to True if agenda.

\begin{document}
\textbf{Meeting of 20 Aug}
\iffalse 
\begin{minutes}
\begin{center}\emph{Meeting Opened at [Time]}\end{center}
\begin{business}
\item Business Item 1

Some details about BI1

\item Business Item 2

Some details about BI1

\item Et Cetera

\end{business}
\begin{center}\emph{Meeting Closed at [Time]}\end{center}
\end{minutes}
\nextmeeting{[Some Date], [Some Time], [Some Place]}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: The normal model is not to do this at all, just have one `\documentclass` per document, there is no need to have more, as you can share the body of the documents and input the body into different documents with different `\documentclass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the file `mins.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/tmp/mins.tex` you can use your Meeting files as is:

```
\documentclass{labbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\input{mins}%%%%%%%%%    mins.tex is in the directory of main.tex
\title{Diary}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Meetings}

    \subfile{Meetings/20Aug}
    %\subfile{Meetings/21Aug} %This will be similar to the one above
    %etc...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works. Thanks. Just the solution I was looking for.